# powers of linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T \in L(V)$, where $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over a field and $L(V)$ is the space of all linear operator. In Sheldon Axler’s textbook, I am asked to verify:

$T^mT^n = T^{m+n}$, and $(T^m)^n = T^{mn}$.

However, I am not sure what the question is asking; is there even anything to verify? It seems to me that there is nothing to be proved here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to show that applying $T$ $n$ times to a vector and then applying it $m$ times to that result, is the same as applying $T$ $m+n$ times to the original vector. Similarly, you need to show that applying $T^m$ $n$ times to a vector is the same as applying $T$ $mn$ times to the original vector.

Comment: This really just follows from how composition of functions works and the definition of $T^a$ for $a\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow okay, so given arbitrary vector $u$, $T(Tu) = T^2u$, so does this suffice as a proof? (Then expand the argument to $T^m T^n$ by induction)

Comment: I think it's easier than that. By definition, $T^m$ is $T$ composed with itself $m$ times, and $T^n$ is $T$ composed with itself $n$ times. So if you compose $T^m$ with $T^n$, this is $T$ composed with itself $m+n$ times, so, by definition, $T^mT^n=T^{m+n}$.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow Thanks! (You basically answered my question, so feel free to just copy and paste your solution as an answer, and I will accept it.)

Comment: No problem. A very similar argument proves the other result as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, $T^m$ is $T$ composed with itself $m$ times, and $T^n$ is $T$ composed with itself $n$ times. So if you compose $T^m$ with $T^n$, this is $T$ composed with itself $m+n$ times. So by definition, $T^mT^n=T^{m+n}$.

Similarly, if we compose $T^m$ with itself $n$ times, this is the same as $T$ composed with itself $mn$ times, thus by definition we have $(T^m)^n=T^{mn}$.